# Bootstrap - Html body isn't taking full width on mobile screen

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm having a problem when using Twitter-Bootstrap CSS framework. On mobile screens, it's not taking up full body width.

The following image will help you understand my issue.

[image: ScreenShot]

There are no CSS styles applied on the body except bootstrap's own. But when I hover on the body element, it shows that it's only taking half the space.

I don't use bootstrap often but I have had this issue before and couldn't figure out how to solve it. I have also seen a few other web pages from different developers having the same issue when using bootstrap.

I just wanna know if many of us are doing something wrong consistently or is this a bug in Bootstrap?

Would love to know how to solve the issue as well.

Let me know if I need to share my code here and I'll do it.

Thanks in advance.

P.S: I have seen this issue on different subversions of bootstrap4. I'm using bootstrap v4.1.3.

Edit 1:

You can check another website using bootstrap with the same issue [here](https://contentdrips.com/)

Comment: There's something strange in the image. At the top the width is set to 315, and that's what the body width is. Perhaps it's some weird thing with the browser responsive preview feature. Have you tried to change it to a particular device type instead of general "Resposive"? Will it track the size correctly then?

Comment: 'Strange' is the correct word here. To answer your question: Yes, I have tried using specific devices in chrome as well as a physical device. It's still the same as the image above. The body width is actually shown correctly which is 315px but the content is not taking the full width.
P.S: Check my edit

Comment: I now suspect that this behavior is caused by some fixed-positioned element having width larger than the body. In your image there's a long element at the top.

Comment: That's bootstrap navbar which is not fixed. It shows long cause the webpage is not mobile friendly.

Comment: You need to look into why it's sticking out so or better yet make it responsive.